# Is there a mathematical method to draw a circle tangent to three other circles and give it's equation?

Tags: geometry

I was curious as to whether there is a mathematical method by which one can draw a circle which is tangent to three other circles and give it's equation. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is the famous [Problem of Apollonius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a circle with centre $(x_s,y_s)$ and radius $r_s$ touches three circle with centres $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ and radii $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3$ respectively,

then $(x_s-x_1)^2+(y_s-y_1)^2=(r_s-s_1r_1)^2$,

$(x_s-x_2)^2+(y_s-y_2)^2=(r_s-s_2r_2)^2$,

and $(x_s-x_3)^2+(y_s-y_3)^2=(r_s-s_3r_3)^2$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius